# Discord music bot fiding yt video

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi i would like to know how to make my bot play music based on YouTube search because the url copying and pasting pisses me off.The bot have youtube_dl and ffmpg. Here is updateted code its still doesn't working. Sorry for my bad english.

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, url: str):

    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
            print("Usunięto starą piosenke.")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Próbuję usunąć plik utworu, ale jest on odtwarzany ")
        await ctx.send(":no_entry_sign:  Muzyka już gra!")
        return

    await ctx.send(":mag_right: Szukanie i Pobieranie")

    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    yt = yt_search.build(url)
    search_result = yt.search("keyword", sMax=10, sType=["video"])
    print(search_result)

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ytdl:
        if url[:4] == 'http':
            ytdl.download([url])
        else: # "yts" is youtube-search imported as
            link = json.loads(yts(url, max_results=1).to_json())['videos'][0]['url_suffix']
            link = 'https://www.youtube.com' + link
            ytdl.download([link])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            print(f"Zmnieniono nazwe: {file}\n")
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: print("Koniec!"))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.17

    nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
    await ctx.send(f" :notes: Teraz Leci: `{nname[0]} - {nname[1]}`")
    print("Puszczanie\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

look up documentation on youtube-search. Here's an example:

```
  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ytdl:
    if url[:4] == 'http':
      ytdl.download([url])
    else: # "yts" is youtube-search imported as
      link = json.loads(yts(url, max_results=1).to_json())['videos'][0]['url_suffix']
      link = 'https://www.youtube.com' + link
      ytdl.download([link])
```

Basically saying "if it starts with http then just use as a link. Else, use youtube-search to get a link for the first search result on YouTube." This probably isn't a good way to do it, maybe use a try/except to see if the search works as a link first, with the except retrying passing in the fetched link.

Comment: did you import json and youtube_search

Comment: yes i imported and its still doesnt working

Comment: when you type a command and a song name bot writes that he is looking for the song and then just nothing happens in terminal or on discord, there is no error

Comment: I edited the question it was too long for comment

Comment: make sure to match the variable names. for example, your youtube-dl options are called "ydl_options", while the with statement passes in "options".